# PHP) how to make json multiple arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm new to json and php,
I trying to encode arrays into JSON object.

I tried this JSON array:

```
<?php
    $requestJson = json_encode([
        'orderNumber'=> "502763-20171027-00006701",
        'PackageModelList'=>
        [
          (
            "basketId": 10666496,
            "SenderModel": 
            (
              "phoneNumber": "5678"
            ),
            "ItemModelList": 
            [
              (
                "itemDetailId": 10666496
              )
            ]
          ),
          (
            "basketId": 10666497,
            "SenderModel": 
            (
              "phoneNumber": "5678"
            ),
            "ItemModelList": 
            [
              (
                "itemDetailId": 10666497
              )
            ]
          )
        ]       
    ]);

?>
```

but this result is this.

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':' in C:\test.php on line 7

I modfied : to =>, but same result.

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in C:\test.php on line 7

What is problem?
Thanks in advance for reply.

Comment: What are those parentheses (ie `(` and `)`) meant to be? You seem to be mixing up PHP array syntax with _something_ else

Comment: the parameter you passed is not a valid array..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 1):

Your code error because you use `(`, `)`, `:` in array, array in PHP use `[`, `]`, `=>`.

`(`, `)`, `:` is JSON code.

```
"basketId": 10666496,
"SenderModel": 
(
  "phoneNumber": "5678"
),
```

Its Json Code.

you can replace

- "(" to "["
- ")" to "]"
- ":" to "=>"

You can try this

```
<?php
$requestJson = json_encode([
  'orderNumber'=> "502763-20171027-00006701",
  'PackageModelList'=>
  [
    [
      "basketId"=> 10666496,
      "SenderModel"=> 
      [
        "phoneNumber"=> "5678"
      ],
      "ItemModelList"=> 
      [
        "itemDetailId"=> 10666496
      ]
    ],
    [
      "basketId"=> 10666497,
      "SenderModel"=> 
      [
        "phoneNumber"=> "5678"
      ],
      "ItemModelList"=> 
      [
        "itemDetailId"=> 10666497
      ]
    ]
  ]       
]);

?>
```